# TRX to HTML using TRXER - formatexception invalid string for TimeSpan

Tags: visual-studio-2012, trx

I am using the following utility from the link https://github.com/NivNavick/trxer.

I get the following error when I try to execute the same to generate the report.

> TrxerConsole.exe unitestresult.trx.trx
>   Trx File
>   unitestresult.trx.trx
>   Loading xslt template...
>   Loading css...
>   Loading javascript...
>   Transforming...
>   Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid TimeSpan.
>   at System.Globalization.TimeSpanParse.TryParseTimeSpan(String input, TimeSpan
>   StandardStyles style, IFormatProvider formatProvider, TimeSpanResult& result)
>   at System.Globalization.TimeSpanParse.Parse(String input, IFormatProvider for
>   matProvider)
>   at System.TimeSpan.Parse(String s)
>   at System.Xml.Xsl.CompiledQuery.Script1.ToExactTimeDefinition(String duration
>   )
>   at System.Xml.Xsl.CompiledQuery.Query.(XmlQuery
>   Runtime {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}runtime, XPathNavigator {urn:schem
>   as-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}current, Double {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debu
>   g}position, Double {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}last, IList1 {urn:sche mas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}namespaces, IList1 testId, IList`1 testDescription
>   )
>   at System.Xml.Xsl.CompiledQuery.Query.

If anybody has gone through similar issue, please let me know how to resolve this.

Thanks
Murali

Comment: Reformat error for better readability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue. There was some problem with String format returned by one of the API in XSLT provided by the Trxer tool. I have updated the same in trxer git hub.Please refer to the below link for the fix.

https://github.com/NivNavick/trxer/pull/17/files